# Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile gives error Value can not be null for Parameter name s

Tags: powershell, azure

I am using Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile after downloading the publish settings Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile but I get the following error:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile : Value can not be null.
Parameter name: s
At line:1 char:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile PowerShell command runs it creates configuration specific setting files in the local machine located as below:

```
C:\Users\<Windows_Login_User_Name>\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell
```

- config.json
- DefaultSubscriptionData.xml
- publishSettings.xml

And in some cases the above files are corrupted due to any reason and above problem may occur. If that is the case, go ahead and delete all the files in above location and then try again the same command. This will re-generate the configuration files again the publish settings will be imported.